# constexpr with the precompile macro #if

Tags: c++, c++17

```
constexpr bool bFooOrBar = true;
void test()
{

#if (bFooOrBar ==true)
    cout << "foo" << endl;
#else
    cout << "bar" << endl;
#endif
}
```

It wouldn't work for expecting output `foo`. I know it works for an ordinary `if else` statement. But why not for the precompile macro #if?

Comment: The pre-processor (i.e. the program that evaluates #if directives) is executed before the compiler and therefore has no knowledge of the remainder of the code. You could use the pre-processor to process any type of file and not just C/C++ and it would work fine because it only looks at the #-directives and nothing else.

Comment: @Lehks, That last sentence isn't quite true. For starters, the preprocessor operates on preprocessing tokens that are defined by C and C++. Even if it were to only look at lines starting with `#`, it would miss line splices and block comments in normal C and C++ code.